# equals() и hashCode() в Java

Tags: java

Если мы переопределяем `equals()`, то обязаны переопределить `hasCode()`.
Причем в обоих методах желательно использовать одни и те же поля класса.
Причем, если `equals()` дает `true`, то и `hashCode()` должен быть одинаковым.

Возникает вопрос: а почему бы при переопределении `equals()` тогда просто не сравнивать `hashCode()`?

Comment: Это не так на самом деле. Читай документацию и назначение методов.

Answer (score 0):

Если для двух объектов `hashCode` возвращает одинаковое значение - это не означает, что это тот же самый объект.

Но если `equals` для двух объектов возвращает `true`, то их `hashCode` будет одинаковый.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм расчёта хэшкода в классе `Object` не учитывает содержимое класса и реализован так, что при каждом запуске программы, даже у экземпляра класса с одним и тем же содержимым хэш будет разным.

Поэтому, если Вы будете сравнивать экземпляры класса по хэшкоду без переопределения метода `hashCode()` у Вас всегда будет `false`.

Собственно, из-за этого и рекомендуется переопределять метод `hashCode()`.

Метод `equals()` отвечает за определение эквивалентности объектов. Но, и он в классе `Object` не идеален, т.к. сравнивает лишь ссылки на объекты без учёта их содержимого. Потому его то же рекомендуют переопределять.

Как программист будет определять эквивалентность двух объектов с учётом их содержимого в `equals()` по большому счёту его личное дело. Только при вычислении хэшкода возможны, т.н. коллизии. Когда два разных объекта имеют одинаковый хэш. По этой причине одинаковые хэшкоды двух и более объектов, ещё не гарантия их эквивалентности. Поэтому при переопределении `equals()` просто сравнивать `hashCode()` нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритмы получения хеш не гарантируют уникальности получаемых значений для разных входных данных. Например слова "Siblings" и "Teheran" имеют идентичный хеш:

```
jshell> "Siblings".hashCode()
$7 ==> 231609873

jshell> "Teheran".hashCode()
$8 ==> 231609873

jshell> Objects.equals("Teheran", "Siblings")
$10 ==> false
```

Это пример коллизии хеш-функции, дело в том, что хеш-функция должна из любого входящего значения произвольной длинны вернуть число ограниченной длинны, в случае метода hashCode это 4-х байтовое целое число, которое может принимать одно из 2^32 возможных значений (это чуть больше четырех миллиардов).

Основным требованием к хэш-функции является равномерность распределения возвращаемых значений при случайном выборе аргументов. Но это не исключает возникновение коллизий. Например большинство сайтов не хранит в базе пароли пользователей в открытом виде, а только их хеш, полученный, например, посредством алгоритма md5. Этот алгоритм вернет 128-битное число, а это значит, что подобрать пароль будет возможно при переборе 2^128 возможных вариантов. Причем полученное, при переборе, входное значение не обязательно будет совпадать с фактическим паролем, но иметь точно такой же хеш.

Метод equals в java объектах как раз и нужен чтоб исключить влияние коллизий на нахождение элементов в коллекциях использующих hashCode и equals, это такие коллекции как HashMap и HashSet. Они используют метод hashCode для определения "места" где должен находится объект, в случае коллизии объекты имеющие идентичный хеш помещаются в список. Поиск среди таких объектов будет осуществляться перебором с вызовом метода equals для каждого элемента списка.